# Mysql subdate query: retrieve records from yesterday/last week/etc

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, debian

I am trying to query a mysql database to return all records that have occurred since yesterday. My mysql version is 5.5.41 (Ubuntu). Here is the query I have that is returning no records:

```
select * from table_name
where column_name between subdate(CURDATE(), 1) and CURDATE();
```

I've also tried this, with no results:

```
SELECT sum(column_name BETWEEN subdate(current_date(), 1) and current_date()) AS Total FROM table_name;
```

I should add that the column_name I am running this query on is in this form: 12 Feb 2015 (18:25)

Note: It looks like this is a formatting issue. I've run this datetime formatting:

```
$old = date('d M Y (h:i)');
$old_timestamp = strtotime($old);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_timestamp);
```

But while *echo $old* renders this: 24 Jul 2015 (09:20), *echo $new_date* outputs the wrong time (1970-000:00:00).

Comment: not sure that your 2nd query is right or wrong but one thing you are missing in 2nd query is `AS` e.g `sum(do your stuff) AS Total` and in PHP you will echo `Total `

Comment: thanks - i've added your correction..

Comment: It's more like you have to check the query after correction that its working or not, making correction in question won't resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(subdate(current_date, 1)) 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_date));
```

Comment: why should OP try this, good answer must explain what OP was doing wrong and the code in your answer do what.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, dateInserted, NOW()) < 1`

The record in question needs to have an appropriate datetime set on it for this to work - in my example, I've provided the column as `dateInserted`

More info on the `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, my first issue was my date was being recognized as a string; so some formatting had to occur to have the date portion recognized as an official date format. Then I could use any number of functions, including the `subdate()` function. Otherwise, the default output on any string was 1970-000:00:00. This worked for me:

```
$date=date('Y-m-d');
$olddate = date('d M Y', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE SUBSTRING(column_name,1,11)=".$olddate;
```